# Finding the best results using Tags

Tags: mysql, sql, search, tags

I want to create a site that uses tags to find a best matching result (a post). A user can like/dislike things and in turn builds a "profile" for himself that consists of tags he likes (and tags he dislikes) based on the things he likes/dislikes.

For example:

```
USER_1 likes: dog, mouse, blue, house
USER_1 dislikes: cat, pink
USER_2 likes: red, hat, blue
USER_2 dislikes: pink
...
```

Now for the posts I have similar tags in the database. For example:

```
POST_1 tags: dog, red, hat
POST_2 tags: blue, pink, cat
...
```

My question is:

How can I get the best matching result (based on likes alone | including dislikes)? Is there a system that has been established or how does one usually solve problems like these?

*E.g. USER_2 first receives POST_2 because it matches his like "blue" and "hat", after that comes POST_1 because he likes "blue".*

Thanks! I'm eager to learn how this works but I haven't found anything (and don't know where to start).